# Input Value is not getting updated when state object is set to undefined

Tags: react-hooks, onchange, react-functional-component

I have list of options (radio button) and on selection of each option, it will display some input fields to take value from user. These values are stored in state "Dimensions". On option change, I am resetting the dimension object to undefined. But this is value is not getting updated in the input field and it is taking old values.

Text field:
`<input  value={dimensions ? dimensions[opt?.value?]: undefined}/>`

On Option Change Method:

```
  const handleOptionChange = (e: any) => {
         setDimensions(undefined);
    };
```

Can anybody please guide me through this.

Thanks inadvance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ReactJS, input value should always be defined, even if it is an empty string

```
<input  value={dimensions ? dimensions[opt?.value?]: ''}/>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much..How simple it was! But i am curious, as why it was not overriding the when I was setting the value to undefined.